# Convert TS-Stream to MKV with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mkv, transport-stream, matroska

I'm using ffmpeg 3.2.7 and I have a problem converting a ts-file lossless to mkv.
The source file is a dumped IPTV-stream recorded with dumprtp (from dvbstream 0.5).

`ffmpeg -i Test.ts -map 0:0 -map 0:2 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f matroska Test.mkv`

The convertion is successful, but the output file is pixelated every few seconds.

When I'm converting it with MKVToolnix everything looks fine.

Does anyone has a solution for that problem?
Maybe some option to sync the stream correctly?

Here's a sample output:

```
# ffmpeg -i Test.ts -map 0:0 -map 0:2 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f matroska Test.mkv
ffmpeg version 3.2.7 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (OpenWrt GCC 6.3.0 r212-46f973b)
  configuration: --enable-cross-compile --cross-prefix=i486-openwrt-linux-gnu- --arch=i386 --target-os=linux --prefix=/opt --pkg-config=pkg-config --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --disable-doc --disable-debug --disable-lzma --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --disable-outdevs --enable-avresample --enable-libopus --enable-small --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[NULL @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[NULL @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] no frame!
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mp3 @ 0x81fb860] Header missing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] no frame!
[mp3 @ 0x81fb860] Header missing
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] no frame!
[mp3 @ 0x81fb860] Header missing
    Last message repeated 3 times
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] no frame!
[mp3 @ 0x81fb860] Header missing
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] no frame!
[mp3 @ 0x81fb860] Header missing
    Last message repeated 3 times
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] no frame!
[mp3 @ 0x81fb860] Header missing
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] no frame!
[mp3 @ 0x81fb860] Header missing
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] no frame!
[mp3 @ 0x81fb860] Header missing
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] no frame!
[mp3 @ 0x81fb860] Header missing
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] no frame!
[mp3 @ 0x81fb860] Header missing
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] no frame!
[mp3 @ 0x81fb860] Header missing
    Last message repeated 7 times
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] no frame!
[mp3 @ 0x81fb860] Header missing
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] reference picture missing during reorder
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] Missing reference picture, default is 2147483647
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] mmco: unref short failure
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] number of reference frames (0+5) exceeds max (4; probably corrupt input), discarding one
[mp3 @ 0x81fb860] Header missing
    Last message repeated 3 times
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] reference picture missing during reorder
    Last message repeated 2 times
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] Missing reference picture, default is 65627
    Last message repeated 2 times
[mp3 @ 0x81fb860] Header missing
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] mmco: unref short failure
    Last message repeated 3 times
[h264 @ 0x81f9580] Increasing reorder buffer to 2
[mp3 @ 0x81fb860] Header missing
    Last message repeated 295 times
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mp3 @ 0x81fb860] Header missing
    Last message repeated 13 times
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mp3 @ 0x81fb860] Header missing
    Last message repeated 2 times
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] decoding for stream 1 failed
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] PES packet size mismatch
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] Could not find codec parameters for stream 1 (Audio: mp3, 0 channels, s16p): unspecified frame size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mpegts, from 'Test.ts':
  Duration: 00:01:00.54, start: 48882.340000, bitrate: 3181 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264, yuv420p(tv, bt470bg, top first), 720x576 [SAR 16:11 DAR 20:11], 25 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x103]: Audio: mp3, 0 channels, s16p
    Stream #0:2[0x102]: Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 192 kb/s
    Stream #0:3[0x101]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 384 kb/s
Output #0, matroska, to 'Test.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg, top first), 720x576 [SAR 16:11 DAR 20:11], q=2-31, 25 fps, 50 tbr, 1k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp2 (P[0][0][0] / 0x0050), 48000 Hz, stereo, 192 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
.
.
.
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 192
    [mpegts @ 0x81f6280] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 0x81f6280] PES packet size mismatch
frame= 2971 fps=2674 q=-1.0 Lsize=   17441kB time=00:00:59.90 bitrate=2385.2kbits/s speed=53.9x    
video:16037kB audio:1410kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

Thank you

Comment: Upgrade to latest ffmpeg build (git HEAD) and try.

Comment: 3.2.7 is the latest version I can get through Entware-ng. I already got this behavior since a long time, so I don't think they fixed it in the last months.

Comment: Try mp4box then.

Comment: Can you upload a small sample?

Comment: I uploaded a one minute sample: test.ts (original source), ffmpeg.mkv (pixelated at 00:14, 00:16, 00:27, 00:38, 00:47, 00:53). When I convert it with MKVToolnix everything looks fine (mkvmerge.mkv). https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-xLtpU-lgG4NUpvVmdZUktiejQ

Comment: mp4box doesn't do the trick either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your input stream playing fine using multiple players. The .ts looks better than the mkv in all players tough, i guess due to error correction infos in the .ts but in the end it does not play 100% fine. Looking at the output of ffplay there are lots of mpeg related errors which means you just do not have all video data in your stream dump to decode it correctly.

Unfortunately there is no way for you to go with direct stream copy from your fragmented .ts file into a frame accurate container without Decoding and re-encoding i fear.

Comment: I agree with you that the .ts does not look fine. But I don't understand why everything looks good after I converted it with MKVToolnix (mkvmerge.mkv) instead of ffmpeg (ffmpeg.mkv)?

Comment: You should update your question with that additional query and add all the details about your MKVToolnix usage. Anyway, my first guess would be that Toolnix is able to use some of the forward error correction info in the input .ts. TS was a problem in ffmpeg ever since ;-)

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Since ffmpeg is not able to do forward error correction successfully, I did a workaround using a MKVToolnix-version that supports .ts-files for my use case (v9.6.0).